# Force on a wall due to a static fluid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

Suppose a tank has a wall of width $8m$ and is filled with water to a depth of $2m$ and we want to find the force applied by the water to the wall.  Do we need Calculus to find this?  It seems to me we do, although this is related to a problem from a book where calculus is generally not necessary.  I would think the pressure varies with depth so that we need to integrate the force per area (or just pressure) at every depth point.

[Edit: In case anyone's curious, here is the exact statement of the problem.

> A large aquarium of height 5.00
>   m is filled with fresh water to a depth of
>   2.00 m. One wall of the aquarium consists
>   of thick plastic 8.00 m wide. By how much
>   does the total force on that wall increase
>   if the aquarium is next filled to a depth of
>   4.00 m?

I'm guessing there's a trick to it so that I don't actually have to find the forces and subtract them, but rather can do something else.  I'm still thinking about what the other thing is that I can do and am not really asking about that--but it just got me to wondering, if I did want to directly find the respective forces, wouldn't I need to use integration?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the pressure is varying linearly with depth, all you need to do is use the average pressure (half way down) to calculate the force.  This gives you the same result as doing the integration.  But, be careful when they are asking for the change as a result of increasing the depth.  In that case, it's easier to calculate the initial and the final forces, based on the different depths.

Answer (score 2):

So I just fumbled my way through an integral and eventually got the answer by the method I alluded to in the question.  In short I reasoned for any small depth change the pressure is constant so that on a small horizontal slice at arbitrary height from the bottom, $y$, the force is $F=PA = \rho g y (8\Delta y)$ and so integrating

$$\int_2^4 \rho g y \cdot 8 dy = 8\rho g \int_2^4y\, dy$$

got me the same answer as in the back of the book.  I'm still not sure if there was some other trick to this that avoided Calculus but I guess I understand it well enough that I can move on.